# Script to populate array and send via AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, checkbox

The title should be more specific, I know, but the question is too elaborated to even describe in one title itself... I'm having troubles to pass certain amount of values into one array to post via AJAX. Note that all of this code is for pure understanding of what I want to do.

## Here's the HTML code with a foreach loop inside the table

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <th style="text-align: center;">Select</th>
    <th style="text-align: center;">Name</th>
    <th style="text-align: center;">Situation</th>
    <th style="text-align: center;">Bill</th>
    <th style="text-align: center;">Date Limit</th>
    <th style="text-align: center;">Value of Bill</th>
    <th style="text-align: center;">Own Value</th>
    <th style="text-align: center;">Responsable Name</th>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   <?php
     foreach ($result as $value) {
        echo '<tr style="text-align: center;">
              <td><input style="cursor: pointer;" type="checkbox" value="'. $value['VALUEBILL'] .'" class="check_list"></input>
              <input style="display: none;" type="checkbox" checked="true" value="'. $value['IDTRANSACTION'] .'" name="numControle"></td>
              <td>'. utf8_encode($value['NAME']) .'</td>
              <td>'. $value['SITUATION'] .'</td>
              <td>'. $value['BILL'] .'</td>
              <td>'. $value['DATELIMIT'] .'</td>
              <td>'. $value['VALUEBILL'] .'</td>
              <td>'. $value['OWNVALUE'] .'</td>
              <td>'. utf8_encode($value['RESPONSABLENAME']) .'</td>
              </tr>';
     }

  ?>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

For a better understading, I have one `jQuery` script wich will sum all bills selected and give the result of all of them together, taking the checked `$value['VALUEBILL']` checkboxes.

#### Here's the jQuery script to get and sum all checked checkboxes values.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   update();
});
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
   update();
})
function update(){
   var amount2 = 0;
   $('.check_list').each(function () {
      if (this.checked) {
        amount2 += Number($(this).val());
          checked_boxes ++;
      }
   $("input[name=amount]").val("$"+amount2.toFixed(2));
});
```

### Here's the form where the script sum all values and input:

```
<form name="sentMessage" id="purchases" novalidate>
  <h4 style="margin-top: -5px;">Total:</h4>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="amount2" name="amount" value="" disabled="">
  <button type="submit">Send Payment</button>
</form>
```

***I pointed the code to a better understanding on what I'm doing and to let you know about what the main problem is***

**Q:** So, what do you need, because is not clear at all?

Take note inside the `foreach` loop, it has an ocult `checkbox` with the value of `$value['IDTRANSACTION']`, this is what I need to send aswell with the other `checkbox`... The first `checkbox` have the value of the bill, and the second, the `ID` of transaction, which each one have its unique value, and it's **extremely** important to account all those bills.

So my question is:

- How do I check this box aswell when the first `checkbox` is checked? (I tried a few `jQuery` codes, but they checked ALL of them in a row when I checked the first one, I need to check only the one which is checked, and not the others that `foreach` provide);
- After getting the first issue sorted out, I need to populate one `array` inside the `form` to send in one AJAX post (which is already ready and working properly) to get all the `checkboxes` values with the `ID's` of each one.

That's it... I'm sorry for the long question, but I needed to provide all the info I could so you could understand what I'm trying to do.

Cheers!

Comment: do you know about input type hidden?

Comment: for your first question use the `siblings(".your element name").check()`

Comment: @madalinivascu I'm really trying to understand your pointing, do you even read the question? It's not about hide something dude =)

Comment: it was a suggestion

Comment: @madalinivascu , yes, I know about input type hidden, but the questions I made still prevail, I wonder if you really read the entire post

Answer (score 1):

Use a hidden input and the following js

```
<td><input style="cursor: pointer;" type="checkbox" value="'. $value['VALUEBILL'] .'" class="check_list"></input>
<input type="hidden" class="id_tansaction" value="'. $value['IDTRANSACTION'] .'" name="numControle"></td>

var data = {};
$('.check_list').change(function(){
 var id_tansaction = $(this).val('.id_tansaction').val();
 var valuebill = $(this).parent().find();
      if($(this).is(':checked')) {
         data[id_tansaction] = valuebill;
       } else {
         delete data[id_tansaction];
       }
});
```

the data array is then send via ajax  `data:data`

Comment: Can I use this script outside the foreach function? And then based on what It get populate one array outside the foreach?